# Users can create Azure AD tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory

It looks like by default the tenant. creation is "Yes" from AAD -> User settings

Where it says all users can create the tenant. Should not it be the default "No" ?

Is it a new feature introduced in Azure? and from when? And why its default "Yes"

Screenshot [image: here]

Comment: This article may help you https://itpro-tips.com/new-setting-users-can-create-azure-ad-tenants/

Answer (score 1):

***`By default , users are given some set of permissions. But it all depends on whether the user is the member or a guest user or restricted guest user .`***

***When a new tenant is created , the one who creates that tenant will be the only user and has global admin rights and can have access to creating tenant.***

[image]

- Guest user and restricted guest users doesn’t have directory permissions .
  So if you need to change member access from user settings according to requirement,  you can change that to no.

See [Default user permissions - Azure Active Directory - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions)

[image]

- Earlier tenant creation option itself was not present for user , but restriction to administration portal is by default set to **`NO`** and has to be set yes explicitly anyway to restrict users to admin portal.
  Check this [Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal - ALI TAJRAN](https://www.alitajran.com/restrict-access-azure/)
- In the same way tenant creation must be set to no by newly created tenant admin.

***When I created new user and loggen in , its default settings are according to what admin set*** with his admin privilige.

[image]

**So When I set them using admin user account details**

[image]

**And then created user ,cannot access portal itself , as access to admin portal is restricted.**

[image]

**Or you can make only tenant creation restriction accordingly.**

[image]